# iOS Qt - Load QWidget inside UIView?

Tags: ios, qt, uiview, qwidget

Hopefully my question will make sense. Just started with Qt so bear with me.

I have an app in Objective-C (for iOS) and I'm trying to add a piece of code in Qt into it.

Most of the UI is in Objective-C (meaning I got UIViews, UIViewControllers, ...) and only a part of it should be handle in Qt.

To create a UI element in Qt, I guess I need to create something that inherits from QWidget.

But how would I set the parent of this QWidget to one of my UIView element?

I understand it would be easier to do everything in Qt, but that is just to much work so that is why I am hoping I can keep part of my UI in Objective-C and the other part in Qt.

Thanks for your help

--

### Edit

Well I was following the example from [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qmacnativewidget.html). Even if it is for Mac OS.

```
QWidget * qWidget = new QWidget();
qWidget->move(0, 0);
qWidget->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::red));
qWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton("An Embedded Qt Button!", qWidget);
pushButton->setAttribute(Qt::WA_LayoutUsesWidgetRect);
layout->addWidget(pushButton);
qWidget->setLayout(layout);

// Adjust Cocoa layouts
UIView *uiWidgetView = (__bridge UIView *)((void*)qWidget->winId()); // Fancy cast for ARC

// Add the widget
[self.view addSubview:uiWidgetView];
qWidget->show();
pushButton->show();
```

But it does not seem to work for iOS...
I have two messages:

**- This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()**
Do not know how to fix that one

**- QIOSBackingStore needs to have the same size as its window** 
This one is referenced [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_iOS_known_issues). Does not seem to be fixed yet.

Note: Adding a simple uiview (like a uilabel) to my current view works fine. Just this one that does not seem to render for some reason... :s

Comment: I'm trying to do the same (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32845050/3419103)). Have you made any progress on Qt with UIViews?