# Create a Qt View within Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, qt, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use a [Qt-based library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ix-Di0qRu9c) within a Xamarin.iOS project. As a first step, I'd like to

1. initialize a simple Qt View and
2. place it in an empty ViewController.

I already managed to link the iOS project with QtCore and QtGui. Now I'm struggling with binding Qt's C++ methods with corresponding C# calls.

Has anyone experience with the combination of Xamarin *and* Qt? 
Is this the way to go at all? 
(All I can find on the web is about Xamarin *vs.* Qt...)